# Using "e.g." to introduce another clause

Tags: phrase-usage

I always used *e.g.* to introduce a non-exhaustive list, as in the following sentence.

> He was the school champion of many activities (e.g., chess, badminton, 110m hurdles, and high jump).

Can *e.g.* be used to introduce a clause?

> This can be used by other modules to act accordingly, e.g. field_ui uses it to add operation links to manage fields and displays.

> This is what the former CEO's did too, e.g. John Doe did it when he was CEO between 2001 and 2006.

Comment: Yes, it's used exactly like *for example*. But *eg* (like  *for example*) is an adverbial (or adsentential), not a conjunction, so when it introduces an independent clause it  should be preceded by a semicolon. I always follow it with a comma, but I handwave that in other folks' writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb) said in his comment:

> Yes, it's used exactly like for example. But eg (like for example) is
>   an adverbial (or adsentential), not a conjunction, so when it
>   introduces an independent clause it should be preceded by a semicolon.
>   I always follow it with a comma, but I handwave that in other folks'
>   writing.

Answer (score -2):

From the book [The new well-tempered sentence](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0618382011):

> A comma is used after terms such as *that is, i.e., e.g., and namely* when they are used to introduce a series or an example.

So the information is that "e.g." should be placed between commas.

Comment: Other style guides don't mandate a comma, and anyway the question isn't about punctuation but about introducing a clause rather than a noun phrase.

Comment: @Gilles For the first issue, I took it from a good book, so how I would I know else? For the second issue, placing "e.g." between commas wouldn't make sense at the beginning of a paranthesis, so I assume it is meant for this case (also it says "an example")  I would update my answer when I get more info. But thanks for nudge

Comment: To add to @Gilles comment: It also only states, that is should be followed by a comma, not necessarily placed between commata. So preceding it with a semicolon and following it with a comma, like StoneyB said, is fine.